# What does $g'(f(2))$ mean?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

> Find $g'(f(2)),$ given $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+5}$ and $g(x)=x^2+x$.

My first step was to find $g(f(x)),$ simplify if possible, then find the derivative $g'(f(x)).$ After I did this, I substituted $2$ for $x.$

A few other students we were saying to find the $g'(x),$ then find $f(2),$ then plug it into $g'(x).$ This also makes sense to me but I'm really unsure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The notation $g'(f(2))$ means the function $g'$ evaluated at the point $f(2)$. So the other students are right.

Comment: Ohhh that makes so much sense. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome! If you feel your question has been answered, you should mark it as such by [accepting the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer). (In that way, other users will see already from the list of questions that it has recieved a satisfactory answer.)

Answer (score 2):

> > Find $g'(f(2)),$ given $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+5}$ and $g(x)=x^2+x$.
>
> A few other students we were saying to find the $g'(x),$ then find $f(2),$ then plug it into $g'(x).$
>
> My first step was to **find $g(f(x)),$ then find the derivative $g'(f(x)).$** After I did this, I substituted $2$ for $x.$

The boldfaced part is somewhat incoherent:

- If you *indeed* mean to find the derivative $g'(\color{red}{f(x)})$ and plug in $x=2,$ then you are obtaining the derivative $g'(\color{red}u)$ and plugging in $u=f(x)$ and plugging in $x=2,$ which this gives the same result as what your classmates are doing. That is, $$g'(\color{red}{f(2)}).$$
- On the other hand, if you *actually* mean to find the derivative of $g(f(\color{red}x))$ and plug in $x=2,$ then you are obtaining $$(g\circ f)'(\color{red}2),$$ which gives a different result from the above.

Comment: "find the derivative $g'(f(x))$" while that string of symbols may represent a derivative of something at least some of the time, it is decidedly odd to call it "a derivative".  It would be like writing "find the product $a + b \cdot c$" or "find the square root $1+\sqrt{x+17}$".

Comment: @JBL In the boldfaced part, the OP has likely misidentified $$g'(\color{red}{f(x)})$$ as the derivative of $g(f(\color{red}x))$  (more accurately: misidentified the composition of $f$  inside the derivative of $g$ as the derivative of $g\circ f.)$ The former is akin to the denominator derivative in this excerpt of the inverse function theorem: $$\forall b{\in}J\quad (f^{-1})'(b)=\frac1{f'(\color{red}{f^{-1}(b)})}.$$

Comment: I was confused, cause I had thought that in order to find g′(f(x)) you must take must also multiply it by the derivative of f(x) inside. But from what im understanding, It's different from (g∘f)′(x)? 

Thank you

Comment: @Garish19  g’(f(x)) involves no multiplication; its meaning is explained in the first bullet point; the part in red is not part of its definition but just its input.